# Is it possible to access a function in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

Consider the following code:

```
(function($) {
  function hello(who)
  {
    console.log('Hello: '+who);
  }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  hello('World');
});
```

How would it be possible to access the hello function from outside the anonymous function?

Comment: Umm, question. Why did you pass jQuery as an argument to the anonymous function, and then not assign it a name?

Comment: @tylermwashburn: Just some quick copy-pasting + editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're going to want to eventually add other methods to this closure as well, you could create a namespace using the module pattern:

```
var myAppNamespace = (function($){
  var exports = {}, // the return object
      helloText = 'Hello: '; // private variable

  function concatText() {
    var returnString = '';
    for (var i = 0, il = arguments.length; i < il; i++) {
      returnString += arguments[i];
    }
    return returnString;
  } // private method

  exports.world = 'World'; // public property
  exports.hello = function ( who ) {
    console.log(concatText(helloText, who));
  }; // public method

  return exports; // assign exports to myAppNamespace
}(jQuery));
```

Here the methods and properties are just to show examples of ways to declare things privately and publicly within the closure.  For illustration:

```
myAppNamespace.hello(myAppNamespace.world); // -> Hello: World
myAppNamespace.hello('Bob'); // -> Hello: Bob
myAppNamespace.helloText; // undefined
myAppNamespace.concatText; // undefined
```

Also, I used the `$` argument in the self-executing function so that `jQuery` is passed to something, you'd use `$` internally to access `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this

```
var hello = (function() {
  return function(who)
  {
    console.log('Hello: '+who);
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  hello('World');
});
```

where you are returning a function from the anonymous function that you can then store and access in any scope you like

Comment: This seems to be to be the simplest example of the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($) {
  function hello(who)
  {
    console.log('Hello: '+who);
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    hello('World');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Just move all references to the hello function inside of the scope.